# python networkx weighted centrality measures

Tags: python, network-programming, networkx

I am hoping to calculate weighted centrality measures. The larger the weight, the stronger the connection.

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('a','b',weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('b','c',weight=1.5)
G.add_edge('a','c',weight=1.0)
G.add_edge('c','d',weight=22) 
bet1=nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight='weight', endpoints=False)
bet2=nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight=None, endpoints=False)
print(bet1,bet2)
clo1=nx.closeness_centrality(G, distance='weight')
clo2=nx.closeness_centrality(G)
print(clo1,clo2)
```

Here are my problems:
1. There is no difference between weighted betweenness centrality and unweighted betweenness centrality.
2. The distance should be equal to 1/weight. I tried the following code but it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix this except create a new network where weight=1/weigth.

```
clo1=nx.closeness_centrality(G, distance=1/'weight')
```

Comment: Distance must be the _name_ of the edge attribute. Before using this parameter, calculate the values of the attribute and give it a name. Also, I _do_ see the difference between the centralities: `print(clo1,clo2) >> {'a': 0.12448132780082986, 'b': 0.12345679012345678, 'c': 0.12448132780082986, 'd': 0.04405286343612335} {'a': 0.75, 'b': 0.75, 'c': 1.0, 'd': 0.6}`. Please check your data.

Comment: @DyZ Thank you! How about the problem that betweenness centrality provides the same results whether it's weighted or not?

Comment: Not in my case: `print(bet1,bet2) >>> 
{'a': 0.6666666666666666, 'b': 0.0, 'c': 0.6666666666666666, 'd': 0.0} {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.0, 'c': 0.6666666666666666, 'd': 0.0}`.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you @DyZ